# "return" is not working on change event of input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, file-io

I am running following code it is working fine in chrome/firefox ,not working in IE.in IE after executing return it again enters in the event handler that's why my validation messages not working in IE.(i am using IE10)

added whole event handler :

```
 $('#image-select').change(function (e) {
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
    HideImageValMsg();
    var imageFiles = (apQuery('#image-select'))[0].files;
        var file = imageFiles[0];
        var filename = file.name;
        var imageArr = ["gif", "jpg", "png", "jpeg", "bmp", "tif", "tiff"];
        if (imageArr.indexOf(filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()) == -1) {
            $('#divInvalidImage').removeClass("apUI-hidden");
            $('#image-name').text('');
            $('#image-select').val('');
            return;
        }
        var fileNameWtoext = filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.')) || filename;
        if (fileNameWtoext.startsWith('.') || fileNameWtoext.endsWith('.') || /[%&*"'?#<>:{}(),.\/|~\\]+/gi.test(fileNameWtoext) || file.size == 0) {
            $('#divInvalidImageNm').removeClass("apUI-hidden");
            $('#image-name').text('');
            $('#image-select').val('');
            return;
        }
        if (fileNameWtoext.length > 100) {
        $('#divFileLength').removeClass("apUI-hidden");
            $('#image-name').text('');
            $('#image-select').val('');
            return;
        }
        $('#image-name').text(imageFiles[0].name);
});
```

Is there any alternative or issues with this code?

Comment: What do you expect that `return` statement to do? You don't return a specific value (so it returns `undefined`), and it is the last line of the function, so the function would have returned at that point anyway and should behave the same way with or without the `return`.

Comment: i am using return to show validation messages on change event of file uplaod.and return false is also not working.

Comment: What is purpose of `return`? You can use `accept` attribute to specify valid file types which `<input type="file">` element should accept, and `css` to display elements in `document`, respectively.

Comment: @guest271314 can you show me how i can use this accept attribute?

Comment: `<input type="file" 
         name="file"
         accept=".gif,.jpg,.png,.jpeg,.bmp,.tif,.tiff" />` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept. Note, `accept` attribute does not restrict user from selecting file other than extensions set as value of the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling change event for an input #image-select and you are changing the value of it inside your function,so after executing return it again goes inside change event handler for the value you are setting by,

```
 $('#image-select').val('');
```

so you can try following code where in the beginning of your change event handler you can check for the value of input and again return false from there,

```
 $('#image-select').change(function (e) {
      if ($('#image-select').val() == "") {
        return false;
    }   
      //Add your code here...
   });
```

Here no need to add following line to prevent callback,

```
 event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
```

Let me know if you face any issues with this.